# latex error "undefined control sequence" \begin{document}

Tags: moderncv

I am preparing a document in Latex and it shows error "Undefined control sequence" for `\begin{document}`
Here is the code I have tried

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

Content

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) to function properly, it requires you to specify at least `\firstname` and `\lastname` within the preamble since these are used to populate the PDF document properties (using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) at the end of the preamble, even though it might not be used within the document (such as your minimal example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\firstname{First}
\lastname{Last}

\begin{document}

Content

\end{document}
```